# Replacing macro-style class method with a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, with-statement, contextmanager

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a good grasp on decorators despite having read many an article on the subject (including [this][1] very popular one on SO).  I'm suspecting I must be stupid, but with all the stubbornness that comes with being stupid, I've decided to try to figure this out.

That, and I suspect I have a good use case...

Below is some code from a project of mine that extracts text from PDF files.  Processing involves three steps:

1. Set up PDFMiner objects needed for processing of PDF file (boilerplate initializations).
2. Apply a processing function to the PDF file.
3. No matter what happens, close the file.

I recently learned about context managers and the `with` statement, and this seemed like a good use case for them.  As such, I started by defining the `PDFMinerWrapper` class:

```
class PDFMinerWrapper(object):
    '''
    Usage:
    with PDFWrapper('/path/to/file.pdf') as doc:
        doc.dosomething()
    '''
    def __init__(self, pdf_doc, pdf_pwd=''):
        self.pdf_doc = pdf_doc
        self.pdf_pwd = pdf_pwd

    def __enter__(self):
        self.pdf = open(self.pdf_doc, 'rb')
        parser = PDFParser(self.pdf)  # create a parser object associated with the file object
        doc = PDFDocument()  # create a PDFDocument object that stores the document structure
        parser.set_document(doc)  # connect the parser and document objects
        doc.set_parser(parser)
        doc.initialize(self.pdf_pwd)  # pass '' if no password required
        return doc

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.pdf.close()
        # if we have an error, catch it, log it, and return the info
        if isinstance(value, Exception):
            self.logError()
            print traceback
            return value
```

Now I can easily work with a PDF file and be sure that it will handle errors gracefully.  In theory, all I need to do is something like this:

```
with PDFMinerWrapper('/path/to/pdf') as doc:
    foo(doc)
```

This is great, except that I need to check that the PDF document is extractable **before** applying a function to the object returned by `PDFMinerWrapper`.  My current solution involves an intermediate step.

I'm working with a class I call `Pamplemousse` which serves as an interface to work with the PDFs.  It, in turn, uses `PDFMinerWrapper` each time an operation must be performed on the file to which the object has been linked.

Here is some (abridged) code that demonstrates its use:

```
class Pamplemousse(object):
    def __init__(self, inputfile, passwd='', enc='utf-8'):
        self.pdf_doc = inputfile
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.enc = enc

    def with_pdf(self, fn, *args):
        result = None
        with PDFMinerWrapper(self.pdf_doc, self.passwd) as doc:
            if doc.is_extractable:  # This is the test I need to perform
                # apply function and return result
                result = fn(doc, *args)

        return result

    def _parse_toc(self, doc):
        toc = []
        try:
            toc = [(level, title) for level, title, dest, a, se in doc.get_outlines()]
        except PDFNoOutlines:
            pass
        return toc

    def get_toc(self):
        return self.with_pdf(self._parse_toc)
```

Any time I wish to perform an operation on the PDF file, I pass the relevant function to the `with_pdf` method along with its arguments.  The `with_pdf` method, in turn, uses the `with` statement to exploit the context manager of `PDFMinerWrapper` (thus ensuring graceful handling of exceptions) and executes the check before actually applying the function it has been passed.

**My question is as follows:**

I would like to simplify this code such that I do not have to explicitly call `Pamplemousse.with_pdf`.  My understanding is that decorators could be of help here, so:

1. How would I implement a decorator whose job would be to call the `with` statement and execute the extractability check?
2. Is it possible for a decorator to be a class method, or must my decorator be a free-form function or class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I interpreted you goal, was to be able to define multiple methods on your `Pamplemousse` class, and not constantly have to wrap them in that call. Here is a really simplified version of what it might be:

```
def if_extractable(fn):
    # this expects to be wrapping a Pamplemousse object
    def wrapped(self, *args):
        print "wrapper(): Calling %s with" % fn, args
        result = None
        with PDFMinerWrapper(self.pdf_doc) as doc:
            if doc.is_extractable:
                result = fn(self, doc, *args)
        return result
    return wrapped


class Pamplemousse(object):

    def __init__(self, inputfile):
        self.pdf_doc = inputfile

    # get_toc will only get called if the wrapper check
    # passes the extractable test
    @if_extractable
    def get_toc(self, doc, *args):
        print "get_toc():", self, doc, args
```

The decorator `if_extractable` is defined is just a function, but it expects to be used on instance methods of your class.

The decorated `get_toc`, which used to delegate to a private method, simply will expect to receive a `doc` object and the args, if it passed the check. Otherwise it doesn't get called and the wrapper returns None.

With this, you can keep defining your operation functions to expect a `doc`

You could even add some type checking to make sure its wrapping the expected class:

```
def if_extractable(fn):
    def wrapped(self, *args):
    if not hasattr(self, 'pdf_doc'):
        raise TypeError('if_extractable() is wrapping '\
                        'a non-Pamplemousse object')
    ...
```

Comment: You interpreted my goal correctly!  This makes perfect sense.  Just a quick question -- Is it possible (and advisable) to make the `if_extractable` fucntion a `Pamplemousse` class method?  In the interest of form, it would make sense for that functionality to be a part of the `Pamplemousse` class.  In any case, I will be testing your solution, so thank you very much!

Comment: I would say not really because you cant even decorate it as classmethod since it will conflict with using it in the same class. Plus its not a method that would ever get called as a member by someone using the class so you dont need to see it on the object. Its much easier to just keep it as a function in your module and leave it off the class namespace. Its really more of a utility for that class.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator is just a function that takes a function and returns another. You can do anything you like:

```
def my_func():
    return 'banana'

def my_decorator(f): # see it takes a function as an argument
    def wrapped():
        res = None
        with PDFMineWrapper(pdf_doc, passwd) as doc:
            res = f()
        return res
     return wrapper # see, I return a function that also calls f
```

Now if you apply the decorator:

```
@my_decorator
def my_func():
    return 'banana'
```

The `wrapped` function will replace `my_func`, so the extra code will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try along the lines of this:

```
def with_pdf(self, fn, *args):
    def wrappedfunc(*args):
        result = None
        with PDFMinerWrapper(self.pdf_doc, self.passwd) as doc:
            if doc.is_extractable:  # This is the test I need to perform
                # apply function and return result
                result = fn(doc, *args)
        return result
    return wrappedfunc
```

and when you need to wrap the function, just do this:

```
@pamplemousseinstance.with_pdf
def foo(doc, *args):
    print 'I am doing stuff with', doc
    print 'I also got some good args. Take a look!', args
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the second block of code.  Is the `@pamplemousseinstance.with_pdf` supposed to be `self.with_pdf`?  `Pamplemousse.with_pdf`?  Also, `foo` would be a class method, but I suppose this doesn't really change anything, right?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to suggest using a class instance as the decorator. This would require creating an instance immediately in the global scope since decorators are applied when the module is loaded

Comment: @jdi Hrm, that’s actually a good point. However, considering his dynamic version was accessing a class field anyways, it might be better to not use technical '@' decorators anyways. Also, `pamplemousseinstance` is an instance of Pamplemousse. It might be better to make it just `Pamplemousse` and a classmethod.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some demonstration code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

class Doc(object):
    """Dummy PDFParser Object"""

    is_extractable = True
    text = ''

class PDFMinerWrapper(object):
    '''
    Usage:
    with PDFWrapper('/path/to/file.pdf') as doc:
        doc.dosomething()
    '''
    def __init__(self, pdf_doc, pdf_pwd=''):
        self.pdf_doc = pdf_doc
        self.pdf_pwd = pdf_pwd

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.pdf_doc

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass

def safe_with_pdf(fn):
    """
    This is the decorator, it gets passed the fn we want
    to decorate.

    However as it is also a class method it also get passed
    the class. This appears as the first argument and the
    function as the second argument.
    """
    print "---- Decorator ----"
    print "safe_with_pdf: First arg (fn):", fn
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kargs):
        """
        This will get passed the functions arguments and kargs,
        which means that we can intercept them here.
        """
        print "--- We are now in the wrapper ---"
        print "wrapper: First arg (self):", self
        print "wrapper: Other args (*args):", args
        print "wrapper: Other kargs (**kargs):", kargs

        # This function is accessible because this function is
        # a closure, thus still has access to the decorators
        # ivars.
        print "wrapper: The function we run (fn):", fn

        # This wrapper is now pretending to be the original function

        # Perform all the checks and stuff
        with PDFMinerWrapper(self.pdf, self.passwd) as doc:
            if doc.is_extractable:
                # Now call the orininal function with its
                # argument and pass it the doc
                result = fn(doc, *args, **kargs)
            else:
                result = None
        print "--- End of the Wrapper ---"
        return result

    # Decorators are expected to return a function, this
    # function is then run instead of the decorated function.
    # So instead of returning the original function we return the
    # wrapper. The wrapper will be run with the original functions
    # argument.

    # Now by using closures we can still access the original
    # functions by looking up fn (the argument that was passed
    # to this function) inside of the wrapper.
    print "--- Decorator ---"
    return wrapper


class SomeKlass(object):

    @safe_with_pdf
    def pdf_thing(doc, some_argument):
        print ''
        print "-- The Function --"

        # This function is now passed the doc from the wrapper.

        print 'The contents of the pdf:', doc.text
        print 'some_argument', some_argument
        print "-- End of the Function --"
        print ''

doc = Doc()
doc.text = 'PDF contents'
klass = SomeKlass()  
klass.pdf = doc
klass.passwd = ''
klass.pdf_thing('arg')
```

I recommend running that code to see how it works. Some of the interesting points to look out for tho:

First you will notice that we only pass a single argument to `pdf_thing()` but if you look at the method it takes two arguments:

```
@safe_with_pdf
def pdf_thing(doc, some_argument):
    print ''
    print "-- The Function --"
```

This is because if you look at the wrapper where we all the function:

```
with PDFMinerWrapper(self.pdf, self.passwd) as doc:
    if doc.is_extractable:
        # Now call the orininal function with its
        # argument and pass it the doc
        result = fn(doc, *args, **kargs)
```

We generate the doc argument and pass it in, along with the original arguments (`*args, **kargs`). This means that every method or function that is wrapped with this decorator receives an addition `doc` argument in addition to the arguments listed in its declaration (`def pdf_thing(doc, some_argument):`).

Another thing to note is that the wrapper:

```
def wrapper(self, *args, **kargs):
    """
    This will get passed the functions arguments and kargs,
    which means that we can intercept them here.
    """
```

Also captures the `self` argument and does not pass it to the method being called. You could change this behaviour my modifying the function call from:

```
result = fn(doc, *args, **kargs)
    else:
        result = None
```

To:

```
result = fn(self, doc, *args, **kargs)
    else:
        result = None
```

and then changing the method itself to:

```
def pdf_thing(self, doc, some_argument):
```

Hope that helps, feel free to ask for more clarification.

EDIT:

To answer the second part of your question.

Yes is can be a class method. Just place `safe_with_pdf` inside of `SomeKlass` **above** and calls to it e.g. The first method in the class.

Also here is a reduced version of the above code, with the decorator in the class.

```
class SomeKlass(object):
    def safe_with_pdf(fn):
        """The decorator which will wrap the method"""
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kargs):
            """The wrapper which will call the method is a doc"""
            with PDFMinerWrapper(self.pdf, self.passwd) as doc:
                if doc.is_extractable:
                    result = fn(doc, *args, **kargs)
                else:
                    result = None
            return result
        return wrapper

    @safe_with_pdf
    def pdf_thing(doc, some_argument):
        """The method to decorate"""
        print 'The contents of the pdf:', doc.text
        print 'some_argument', some_argument
        return '%s - Result' % doc.text

print klass.pdf_thing('arg')
```